# Finding the height of the space above a div

Tags: jquery, html

I have some divs with unique IDs in different places in my webpage. I want to find the exact height of the space above the div (till its find the starting position of the screen) as mentioned in the image below,

[image]

Is there are anyways to do this in jQuery? please help me do this,

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.offset().top` or `.position().top`:

```
console.log($('div[id]').offset().top); // it give you offset top of the document

console.log($('div[id]').position().top); // gives you the containers position 
                                          // from the top if container is 
                                          // relative positoned.
```

find in the fiddle: <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/zVzBQ/</kbd>

```
 $('div[id]').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).offset().top);
 });
```

Comment: Love you Jai, Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can use `offset` if you are wanting them relative to the document:

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

```
$('#a').offset().top
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery function position to get the position of the element/elements
http://api.jquery.com/position/

Answer (score 1):

adding this answer for those looking to find this without jQuery:

```
var distanceTop = document.getElementById( 'elementId' ).offsetTop;
```

or, for those who are nitpicky:

```
var divId = document.getElementById( 'elementId' );
var distanceTop = divId.offsetTop;
```